# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, prompt

```js
let fullName = prompt("Please enter your name :")
let surName = document.querySelector("#surName")
surName.innerHTML =`${surName.innerHTML}${surName}`
```

my piece of code is here and I'm getting an error like this. I can't import data into hmtl with inner.HTML and from prompt. What should I do ? Also index.html file

```html
<h2 id="surName">Javascript Prompt</h2>
```

Comment: Hi, what exactly are you trying to achieve here? It's a little unclear. So your first 2 lines make sense, but are you trying to print the `fullName` in the `h2` tag?

Comment: Hi, sorry I want to write the name entered with the prompt on the html page, but the fullName I entered with the prompt is not written on the html page.

Comment: I added the code below.. The reason it wasn't added is because you were passing `surName` to `#surName`, when you should be passing `fullName` to `#surName`.. :)

Comment: You are most likely trying to read/set the value of an element before it exists on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let fullName = prompt("Please enter your name :");
let surName = document.querySelector("#surName") ;
surName.innerHTML = fullName; // because `fullName` now has the value you enter in the prompt
```

```html
<h2 id="surName">

</h2>
```

Comment: Well that is a bug, but would not cause the error the OP states

Comment: @epascarello Agreed. But I didn't get the error mentioned, the only mistake I noticed was that the `#surName` was the div id but the value of the prompt is set to the `fullName`.. :)

Comment: because your code is set up to run after the element exists.